# Group date intervals by the proximity of their start- and end-times

Tags: r, zoo

Suppose I have a series of observations representing date intervals, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df <-
    data_frame(start = as.Date(c('2000-01-01', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-08',
                                 '2000-01-20', '2000-01-22')),
               end =   as.Date(c('2000-01-02', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-10',
                                 '2000-01-21', '2000-02-10')))
```

I would like to group these observations such that the start time of observation `n` occurs within some specified interval following the end date of observation `n-1`. For instance, if we set that interval to be 5 days, we would see something like:

```
#           start        end group
#          (date)     (date) (dbl)
#    1 2000-01-01 2000-01-02     1
#    2 2000-01-03 2000-01-05     1
#    3 2000-01-08 2000-01-10     1
#    4 2000-01-20 2000-01-21     2
#    5 2000-01-22 2000-02-10     2
```

(For the sake of simplicity, I'm assuming no overlap in dates, although this isn't necessarily the case in the data). I thought about using `igraph` to create a weighted edgelist, but that seemed overly complicated. Efficiency is, I believe, important: I'll be running this on roughly 4 million groups of data of about 5-10 rows each.

While my solution does work, to me it seems error-prone, slow, and clunky. I'm thinking using a package or some vectorization would really improve matters.

```
group_dates <- function(df, interval){
  # assign first date to first group
  df %<>% arrange(start, end)
  df[1, 'group'] <- 1

  # for each start date, determine if it is within `interval` days of the
  # closest end date
  lapply(df$start[-1], function(cur_start){
    earlier_data <- df[df$end <= cur_start, ]
    diffs <- cur_start - earlier_data$end
    min_interval <- diffs[which.min(diffs)]
    closest_group <- earlier_data$group[which.min(diffs)]

    if(min_interval <= interval){
      df[df$start == cur_start, 'group'] <<- closest_group
    } else {
      df[df$start == cur_start, 'group'] <<- closest_group + 1
    }
  })

  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that relatively easily with dplyr.

The idea is the following:

1. Lag the end data (shifting it down by one)
2. Calculate the difference between start date and the lagged end date
3. Adding 'BreakPoints' - A variable with TRUE when the difference is more than 5 days and FALSE otherwise
4. Calculating the cumulative sum of this break-point. This will add 1 every time it find a new breakpoint so a new interval should be started

Something like this should work for you:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(lagged_end = lag(end),
         diff = start - lagged_end,
         new_interval = diff > 5,
         new_interval = ifelse(is.na(new_interval), FALSE, new_interval),
         interval_number = cumsum(new_interval))
```

This should be also quite quick since it's all in dplyr

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as elegant as Lorenzo Rossi's solution, but offers a slightly different approach using `cut.Date` and 2 lines of code:

```
breakpoints <- c(FALSE, sapply(2:nrow(df), function(x) df[x,"start"] - df[x-1,"end"]) > 5)
clusterLabels <- as.numeric(cut.Date(df$start, c(min(df$start), df[breakpoints, "start"], max(df$start)+1)))
```